Face detection not working for landscape picture
I am using the example app to test the face detection feature, but the faces are not detected if the picture is not portrait. There is some setting that I have to change to detect faces on landscape picture? Or is not possible at the moment?



Looks like this is a Google MLKit issue and it hasn't been resolved yet. Here
